# Accessing computer with GUI turned off

Tags: linux, networking

My father, who rather unexpectedly and sadly passed away, had an old linux computer that he used to access remotely (perhaps via telnet?) over our local network from his tablet.

The computer is still running and I would like to access it, fearing that if I shut it down and later restart it, I would not be able to do so due to password restrictions.

I have, of course, physical access to the computer, but the GUI seems to be disabled because when I connected a monitor it didn't get any signal. I don't know the IP-address of the computer and I don't know the password to our router, where I otherwise could have checked it.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: In response to the downvotes, I do not think I am trespassing or violating his privacy. We lived together, and he used to share his passwords with me so I don't think there's anything terribly private on the computer. I might try the passwords that I remember, but I might have forgotten the right one. I was afraid to turn off the computer and kill any current session, but it now seems that it will probably not result in the loss of anything significant.

Comment: For example, how can I turn on the GUI again?

Comment: What is your knowledge of Linux? You might use `ssh`... but you should learn some basic Linux command line skills. You could also use some USB key containing a Linux distro and boot it.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Get the data on the computer's disk? Reinstall Linux on that computer? Is it a desktop or a laptop?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: But how can I get up a terminal that I can use when the GUI is turned off? I don't want to boot it with another Linux distro because I want to see what the computer is currently running.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes, I guess I want the data.

Comment: You don't need any GUI. You need to be able to run a shell (probably as root) on that computer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: How can I do that? Would it be OK to chat?

Comment: The downvote are not related to privacy or ethical concerns. But your question is off-topic here (since not related to any source code of yours). [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) are a better place to ask (notably your *next* questions related to that).

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry about that. Thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My condolence for that loss.

First ask yourself if you really want to dig your late father's data (and privacy). And you might not be able to do something useful with it...

Then, I am supposing you have some basic command line skills on Linux. If you don't, learn them first (on your own machine, perhaps in a VM). That takes several weeks.

Many Linux machines don't have any GUI, since they are accessed with a command line interface (a typical example is of course any VPS hosted elsewhere), often using `ssh` (`telnet` is out of fashion, and I can't imagine your father used that).

Most desktops can be physically reset (by some switch on their motherboard) to clear the BIOS password, etc... You might need to do that. Then you could boot a Linux from some USB key (and that won't harm any data on the disk, if you are careful enough).